# C# calculation errors

Tags: c#

I have a c# code which calculates (304/1000)*100, which equals 30.4, however when I run the code in c# every single time I get 0.

```
decimal width = (maxSize.Width/ maxValue) * value; //304, 1000, 100 respectively
Console.WriteLine(width); //Returns 0
```

I don't understand what the hell is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if you are using `int`s for the operands.

With `int` division, you must remember that the decimal part of the result gets ***truncated***.

I.e., for the line `(304/1000)*100` (replacing the variables with their values for simplicity), the following is calculated:

`304` is divided by `1000`, which results in `0.304`.  Then, the decimal is truncated, since this is integer division, resulting in `0` being the end result.

Then, `0` is multiplied by `100`, which gives `0` as the result.

**Solution:**

Make the operands `decimal`s, `float`s, or `double`s. (`100m`, `100f`, and `100d`, respectively, for an example of each type)

These three types support decimals, so if you use them, you will get the correct result of `30.4`.

Either that, or you can multiply one of the values in the parentheses by `1.0` of any of the three above types:

`(1.0f * 304 / 1000) * 100`

Comment: Thank you <3, you really helped

Answer (score 1):

Your input variables are all of type int. Cast any of them into decimal or suffix the number with the letter M to convert to a decimal before the calculation is performed.

Comment: It doesn't change anything, I still get 0 as a result

Comment: @vxern, your problem is because of the integer division. Hence, you would need to cast one (or both) of the **division operands** to decimal, turning the division from an integer division into an decimal division. Casting the result of the division, or casting the multiplication operand to decimal won't help (as in that case you would then still be left with an integer dvision...) So, yeah, the answer here given is somewhat inaccurate when saying "_Cast any of them [...]_"

Comment: Absolutely correct. I overlooked the detail that there are multiple operators in the equation. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Use correct type

```
maxSize.Width = 304m;
maxValue = 1000m;
value=100m;

decimal width = (maxSize.Width/ maxValue) * value;
```